# clearing cache flush magento storage & cache returns empty screen in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I just cleared the **cache** & **flush** magento **storage&cache** it returns Empty front end,
How to solve the prob,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you recently change your xml layout or any template files?

Comment: i catch ur point jason thank u...

Comment: I'm glad my suggestion worked out for you. In this case, would you mind selecting an answer so this post doesn't linger in the "unanswered" questions lot? ;D

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in your code, and you can't see it due to php settings, so you should look for it in server's error.log.
You can uncomment the line #77 from index.php to have errors displayed in frontend (not recommended in production).

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh your cache, Magento reloads your XML files and updates the front end layout. If you have made any recent changes to your layout that do not load properly, it may cause your page to load incorrectly, or not at all. Check your recent xml changes (you can comment out tags, refresh the cache and check to diagnose layout problems).